# Iterative way of solving of over-determined, complex linear equations system with limited access to A matrix.

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

I got over-determined linear equations system with M equations and N unknowns (M >> N, M is usually less than 100 while N comes to tens of thousads) in complex domain, in matrix notation:

Ax = b

where **A** is complex matrix with **M** rows and **N** columns and **b** is column vector with **M** rows.

The problem is to find such **x** that would minimize above equation with additional assumption that i have direct access ONLY to few consecutive rows of A
(it would be computed on embedded system with limited memory) and the coefficients would arrive in column-row order (e.g. first row of **A**, then second, third and so on).

My question is:

*Is there any iterative algorithm that would allow to compute subsequent approximations of **x** that would be convergent to "optimal" **x** value (in terms of least square) having access only to few adjacent rows of **A** matrix?*

First attempts included:

1. $A^T A x = A^T b \to x ~ (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$ is already working, the problem was in lack of conjugate in transposition (in fact it should be $A^H A x = A^H b \to x ~ (A^H A)^{-1} A^H b$ ) - however, random access to whole **A** matrix is required.
2. QR decomposition with Givens rotation - worked like a charm but requires column-wise access to **A**.

Best regards and thanks in advance :) !

Comment: Do you mean few rows of $A$ at one time? But you access to all of $A$, just not at once?

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Elements of **A** are arriving one after another, in a row-by-row manner (first would be A[0,0], then A[0,1] ... and last A[M-1,N-1].
Due to limited amount of memory i'm able to cache only few adjacent rows of A (e.g. current one and 10 previous).

Comment: I think some form of Bregman Iterative method might work. However, currently I can only use it to solve the problem minimize $\|x\|_2^2 + C\|\xi\|_2^2$ such that $Ax + \xi = b$.

Answer (score 1):

After writing down $A^TA$ it turned out that each result element - computed as dot product of one row of $A^T$ and one column of $A$ - contains sum of products, where each product contains elements from single row of $A$, and so that it is possible to compute $A^TA$ processing only single row at a time.
Thanks for any comments and best regards :)